# How to pass nested fields in a REST API link to filter mongoose nested models

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, mongoose

I'm working on a REST API and I don't know how to filter with a nested field which is `productType.markteplace.name`.

Here are the models:

```
hashtag : {
    name: {type: String },
    productType: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'ProductType',
      required: true
    }
}
```

```
productType:  {
    name: {type: String},
    marketplace: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Marketplace'
    }
  }
```

This is the Controller where the search is

```
    let options = {
      populate: [{
        path: 'supplier',
        model: Supplier
      },
      {
        path: 'productType',
        model: ProductType,
        populate: {
          path: 'marketplace',
          model: Marketplace
        }
      }]
    };
    let search = { };
    if (req.query.search) {
      search.name = req.query.search;
    }
    let conditions = {
      ...req.query.conditions,
      ...search
    };
    Hashtag.paginate(conditions, options).then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    })
```

With this code the normal filter or search like "&name=x" works fine but I'm asking how to filter with the value of the marketplace name "&productType.markteplace.name=x"

Answer (score 0):

Using `find()` you could populate all the collection, then loop through the documents.

```
Hashtag.find({})
  .populate({
        path: 'productType',
        model: ProductType,
        populate: {
          path: 'marketplace',
          model: Marketplace
        }
      })
  .then(function(hashtags) {
    hashtags.find(hashtag => hashtag.productType.marketplace.name == req.query.search)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```